# Image Does Not Animate and is Stuck in one Frame

Tags: android, libgdx, animation, scene2d, android-studio

I'm having a problem in my code where the animation from another class does not animate and is stuck in one frame. The image moves across the screen in the right manner though. I know that the problem is somehow related to the UPDATE method of the animation. I have tried every possible solutions in my knowledge to find what causes the error and the solutions I found online were not quite helpful. Any help will be appreciated.

Here's my Code:

LevelOneScreen.java

```
public class LevelOneScreen implements Screen {

    private final MyGame app;
    WalkAnimate walkAnimate;
    private Stage stage;
    private Image levelOneImage;
    private Image holdStartImage;
    public Image walkRightImage;
    public Image walkLeftImage;
    public float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();




    public LevelOneScreen(final ThumbChase app){
        this.app = app;
        this.stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(app.screenWidth,app.screenHeight , app.camera));

    }
    @Override
    public void show() {

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        walkAnimate = new WalkAnimate();
        walkAnimate.update(deltaTime);


        levelOneBackground();
        holdStart();
        ninjaWalk();


    }



    public void holdStart(){
        Texture holdStartTexture = new Texture("HoldStart.png");
        holdStartImage = new Image(holdStartTexture);
        float holdStartImageW = holdStartImage.getWidth();
        float holdStartImageH = holdStartImage.getHeight();
        float holdStartImgWidth = app.screenWidth*0.8f;
        float holdStartImgHeight = holdStartImgWidth *(holdStartImageH/holdStartImageW);
        holdStartImage.isTouchable();
        holdStartImage.setSize(holdStartImgWidth,holdStartImgHeight);
        holdStartImage.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/2-holdStartImgWidth/2,stage.getHeight()/2-holdStartImgHeight/2);
        stage.addActor(holdStartImage);
        holdStartImage.addListener(new ActorGestureListener(){
           /* public void touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
                holdStartImage.setVisible(false);
            };*/
           public void fling(InputEvent event, float velocityX, float velocityY, int button)  {
               holdStartImage.setVisible(false);
           }
            public void touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
                holdStartImage.setVisible(false);
            };
            public void touchDrag (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
                holdStartImage.setVisible(false);
            };

        });


        }


    public void levelOneBackground(){
        Texture levelOneTexture = new Texture("BGBlue Resize.png");
        levelOneImage = new Image(levelOneTexture);
        levelOneImage.setSize(app.screenWidth,app.screenHeight);
        levelOneImage.setPosition(0,0);
        stage.addActor(levelOneImage);
        /*levelOneImage.addListener(new ActorGestureListener(){
            public void touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
                holdStartImage.setVisible(false);
            };
        });*/
    }
    public void ninjaWalk(){
        TextureRegion ninjaWalkRight = new TextureRegion(walkAnimate.getCurrentFrameRight());
        TextureRegion ninjaWalkLeft = new TextureRegion(walkAnimate.getCurrentFrameLeft());
        //Texture ninjaWalkRight = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        //Texture ninjaWalkLeft = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        walkRightImage = new Image(ninjaWalkRight);
        walkLeftImage = new Image(ninjaWalkLeft);
        float walkImageW = walkRightImage.getWidth();
        float walkImageH = walkRightImage.getHeight();
        float walkImageWidth = app.screenWidth*0.25f;
        float walkImageHeight = walkImageWidth*(walkImageH/walkImageW);
        walkRightImage.isTouchable();
        walkLeftImage.isTouchable();
        walkRightImage.setSize(walkImageWidth,walkImageHeight);
        walkLeftImage.setSize(walkImageWidth,walkImageHeight);
        walkRightImage.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/2-walkImageWidth/2,0);
        walkLeftImage.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/2-walkImageWidth/2,0);
        walkRightImage.addAction(moveBy(app.screenWidth*0.2f,0,1f));
        stage.addActor(walkRightImage);
        walkRightImage.addListener(new ActorGestureListener(){
            public void pan(InputEvent event, float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
                holdStartImage.setVisible(true);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        //walkAnimate.update(deltaTime);
        update(delta);
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime){
        stage.act(deltaTime);

        stage.draw();
        app.batch.begin();

        app.batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();

    }
}
```

WalkAnimate.java

```
public class WalkAnimate {

        public MyGame app;
        public Stage stage;


        private Animation walkAnimationRight;
        private Animation walkAnimationLeft;
        private Texture walkSheetRight;
        private Texture walkSheetLeft;
        private TextureRegion[] walkFramesRight;
        private TextureRegion[] walkFramesLeft;
        private TextureRegion   currentFrameRight;
        private TextureRegion   currentFrameLeft;
        private float stateTime;
        private Rectangle bound; //used for positioning and collision detection
        private static final int  FRAME_COLS_WALK = 3;
        private static final int  FRAME_ROWS_WALK= 2;
        private float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        private float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        public float currentFrameWidth = (float)(screenHeight*0.15);
        public float currentFrameHeight = (float)(screenHeight*0.15);
        public float walkSheetWidth;
        public float walkSheetHeight;



        public WalkAnimate () {

            walkSheetRight = new Texture("ninjaWalkRight.png");
            walkSheetWidth = walkSheetRight.getWidth();
            walkSheetHeight = walkSheetRight.getWidth();
            TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheetRight, (int) walkSheetRight.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS_WALK, (int) walkSheetRight.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS_WALK);
            walkFramesRight = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS_WALK * FRAME_ROWS_WALK];
            int index = 0 ;
            for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS_WALK; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS_WALK; j++) {
                    walkFramesRight[index++] = tmp[i][j];
                }
            }
            walkAnimationRight = new Animation(0.044f, walkFramesRight);
            stateTime = 0f;


            walkSheetLeft = new Texture("ninjaWalkLeft.png");
            walkSheetWidth = walkSheetLeft.getWidth();
            walkSheetHeight = walkSheetLeft.getWidth();
            TextureRegion[][] tmp1 = TextureRegion.split(walkSheetLeft, (int) walkSheetRight.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS_WALK, (int)walkSheetLeft.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS_WALK);
            walkFramesLeft = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS_WALK * FRAME_ROWS_WALK];
            int index1 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS_WALK; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS_WALK; j++) {
                    walkFramesLeft[index1++] = tmp1 [i][j];
                }
            }
            walkAnimationLeft = new Animation(0.044f, walkFramesLeft);
            stateTime = 0f;

            currentFrameRight = walkAnimationRight.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
            currentFrameLeft = walkAnimationLeft.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);




        }


        public Rectangle getBound(){
            return bound;
        }

        public void update(float delta){
            stateTime += delta;



        }


        public TextureRegion getCurrentFrameRight(){
            return currentFrameRight;

        }
        public TextureRegion getCurrentFrameLeft(){
            return currentFrameLeft;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a `Ninja` class for you. You can test it cause I don't have GDX on this PC here:

```
public class Ninja extends Actor {

    private Animation wLeftAnimation, wRightAnimation;
    private static final int  FRAME_COLS_WALK = 3;
    private static final int  FRAME_ROWS_WALK= 2;
    private float stateTime = 0f;



    public enum Direction{
        LEFT,
        RIGHT;
    }

    private Direction currentDirection = Direction.RIGHT;

    public Ninja(){
        Texture walkSheetRight = new Texture("ninjaWalkRight.png");
        Texture walkSheetLeft = new Texture("ninjaWalkLeft.png");


        TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheetRight, (int) walkSheetRight.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS_WALK, (int) walkSheetRight.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS_WALK);
        TextureRegion[] walkFramesRight = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS_WALK * FRAME_ROWS_WALK];
        int index = 0 ;
        for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS_WALK; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS_WALK; j++) {
                walkFramesRight[index++] = tmp[i][j];
            }
        }


        tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheetLeft, (int) walkSheetRight.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS_WALK, (int) walkSheetRight.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS_WALK);
        TextureRegion[] walkFramesLeft = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS_WALK * FRAME_ROWS_WALK];
        index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS_WALK; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS_WALK; j++) {
                walkFramesLeft[index++] = tmp[i][j];
            }
        }

        wLeftAnimation = new Animation(0.044f,walkFramesLeft);
        wRightAnimation = new Animation(0.044f,walkFramesRight);

        setSize(wLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(0f).getRegionWidth(), wLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(0f).getRegionHeight());
        setPosition(0,0);
    }


    public void walkLeft(){
        currentDirection = Direction.LEFT;
        clearActions();
        addAction(Actions.moveBy(-5,0));
    }

    public void moveRight(){
        currentDirection = Direction.RIGHT;
        clearActions();
        addAction(Actions.moveBy(5,0));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);


        final float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        this.act(delta);

        stateTime += delta;

        TextureRegion currentFrame;
        switch (currentDirection){
            case LEFT:
                currentFrame = wLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                currentFrame = wLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
                break;
            default:
                // if you add more states
                currentFrame = wLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
                break;
        }

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(currentFrame, getX(),getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
        batch.end();

    }
}
```

Now in your screen you can create a Ninja:

`Ninja ninja;`

in Screen constructor/onCreate() call:

`ninja = new Ninja();`

add it to the stage:

`stage.add(ninja);`

in your `update()` in `Screen` update and draw your stage like this:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))
            ninja.walkLeft();

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))
            ninja.walkRight();

    update(delta);
}

public void update(float deltaTime){
    stage.act(deltaTime);
    stage.draw(); // this will draw the ninja cause he's on the stage!
}
```

And you can do some magic with his `moveRight()` and `moveLeft()` methods that I wrote. Check if they work and remove the whole `WalkAnimate` class!
Post the errors, cause as I said, I wrote this in a notepad.

**Tip**: Use left and right on keyboard to walk ;)

Comment: Hey man thanks for your help. I made a few corrections but it works :)

Comment: Another problem arises though, the holdStart image does not show after adding ninja to the stage.

Comment: Did you try to change button's size and position after adding ninja and button? Maybe ninja is overlapping the button and hiding it ;C

Comment: The button's position is at the center while the ninja is at 0,0 and the sizes are in no way overlapping each other.

Comment: After adding ninja to stage, the holdStart button is not shown but when I click on its designated position on the screen the background (levelonebackground) turns to black.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. Comment the line where you add your background to the stage: //stage.addActor(levelOneImage);  check if all works without levelOneImage and tell me!

Comment: It only shows the ninja but not the button in a black background.

Comment: So the button is black O.o? Maybe you messed with it's 'setVisible(b)' or the texture is too big and memory can't load it. What's the size of the button texture on disc? (in pixels x pixels)

Comment: No there is no button and the background is black, only the ninja is shown. The button texture is 1000 x 532. It is shown when ninja isn't added to the stage. I didn't mess its visibility.

Comment: Background is black because of this:  `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);` so this is ok. Add the button to the stage again and set it's size and position BEFORE and AFTER adding it

Comment: I know that it's black because of that line of code but what confuses me is that the button disappears when ninja is added to the stage. The button's position and size is set before it is added to the stage.

Comment: Try to set it after it's added and try to call button.setZIndex(999);

Comment: I tried doing that both before and after it's added but it still won't show.

Answer (score 1):

In `LevelOneScreen`, make your `update` method call `update` on `WalkAnimate`:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    walkAnimate.update(deltaTime);

    update(delta);
}
```

Then, in `WalkAnimate`, make sure you select the correct keyframe in the `update` method:

```
public void update(float delta){
    stateTime += delta;
    currentFrameRight = walkAnimationRight.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    currentFrameLeft = walkAnimationLeft.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean putting walkAnimate.update(deltaTime) in update method of LevelOneScreen?

Comment: @JAlmazan No, I meant what I typed in the answer. It looks like you reference the `currentFrameRight` and `currentFrameLeft` directly from `LevelOneScreen` so you need to make sure those are being set to the right values, you do that by updating the key frame in the update method.

Comment: Ok I'll test it but I think I've tried that before.

Comment: It's still stuck in one frame even though I commented out walkAnimate.update(deltaTime) in the render method of levelonescreen, I also put the currentframeright and left in update of walkAnimate

Comment: Checking... :D!

Comment: @Spectre Go ahead man

Comment: I need to rewrite your whole code because there are some bugs and it won't work this way. You are creating an Animation and an Image which is unnecessary, you need only Animation, update it with stateTime, get it's frame and draw it on the batch. I will rewrite your code, but when I get back home in ~5 hours couse I'm at work now ;)

Comment: @Spectre That's fine with me, I'm about to go to school too in 10 mins.

Comment: Can you take a look at my question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136318/how-to-refresh-dependencies-after-adding-freetype-extension-in-android-project

Comment: Guys can you visit my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971321/how-to-restart-screen-in-libgdx-using-init-methods